# AngularJS Controller Not Showing/Hiding Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

I am trying to get content to disappear on button click and then show a new set of content on that button click. I cannot quite get this to work. I commented what each section is doing. The first section *doesn't* disappear on button click. The second section works as expected and *does* disappear on button click and the third section *doesn't* show up on button click. Helps is greatly appreciated and I look forward to learning from this!

I thought by adding a controller it would all function together.

**HTML**

```
<!-- THIS DOESN'T DISAPPEAR ON BUTTON CLICK -->
<div ng-controller="EventCtrl" ng-hide="eventComplete">
    <h2>Example that doesn't disappear on button click</h2>
</div>

<!-- THIS WILL DISAPPEAR ON BUTTON CLICK -->
<div ng-controller="EventCtrl" ng-hide="eventComplete"> 

    <div>
        <h2>Example</h2>
        <md-button ng-click="eventFinish();">Finish</md-button>
    </div>

    <!-- THIS DOESN'T SHOW ON BUTTON CLICK -->
    <div ng-controller="EventCtrl" ng-show="eventComplete">
        <h2>Complete!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
.controller('EventCtrl', function($rootScope,$state,$scope,$timeout){
  var self = this;
  $scope.eventComplete = false;
  $scope.eventFinish=function(){
    console.log('eventFinish'); //This logs
    $scope.eventComplete = true;
  };
})
```

Comment: You should wrap all of your html in `<div ng-controller="EventCtrl"></div>` so you don't have to add ng-controller multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrapped the div you want to hide around the div you want to show. The following html should solve the issue:

```
<div ng-controller="EventCtrl">

    <div ng-hide="eventComplete">
        <h2>Example that doesn't disappear on button click</h2>
    </div>

    <div ng-hide="eventComplete"> 
        <div>
            <h2>Example</h2>
            <md-button ng-click="eventFinish();">Finish</md-button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="eventComplete">
        <h2>Complete!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Found an issue in controller as well. You're missing the closing } for eventFinish :

```
.controller('EventCtrl', function($rootScope,$state,$scope,$timeout){
    var self = this;
    $scope.eventComplete = false;
    $scope.eventFinish = function() {
        console.log('eventFinish');
        $scope.eventComplete = true;
    };
})
```

Comment: This answer was perfect because it is well explained and provides a logical solution with my current setup. It also solved the multiple controller issue without rewriting my code in such a way I couldn't understand it at my current skill level. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid placing same controller inside each other. That will only lead to problems. Instead use [Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

But if you insist on using controllers you could solve it this way. (Code not tested)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="EventCtrl"> 
    <div ng-if="showExample(1)">
        <h2>Example 1</h2>
        <md-button ng-click="onClickExample(2);">Finish</md-button>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="showExample(2)">>
        <h2>Example 2</h2>
        <md-button ng-click="onClickExample(1);">Finish</md-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
.controller('EventCtrl', function($rootScope,$state,$scope,$timeout){

  $scope.currentExample=1;

  $scope.showExample = function(id){
    return $scope.currentExample === id;
  }

  $scope.onClickExample = function(id){
    $scope.currentExample = id;
  } 
});
```